# Purpose of '.status' VHDs that are created when booting an Azure VM

Tags: storage, azure

I'm using the Portal (portal.azure.com) and choosing the Resource Manager view when booting an Ubuntu VM on Azure.  I'm seeing that there are two vhds that are created as part of booting the Instance. I understand that one of these should be a copy of the image I specified when booting the VM but what is the other one for?  It's naming format, something along the lines of "S2.224bb2cd-04e4-43eb-af88-ffbeb754a640.status", leaves me a hint as to what its for but I'm hoping for some specifics here.

This is one of the vhds that is orphaned when an Instance is deleted and I'd like to know a bit about it before I nuke it as part of my clean up scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the file, it just contains some text and dates related to diagnostics updates.  I can't find any documentation specifically about what reads or writes to that file and seems to be updated on the fly. It seems totally safe to delete when you are getting rid of VHDs. I delete them myself.